# TypeScript: What's the difference between a Module and a Class with Static members?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript.

After having a look a modules ( https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html ) I asked myself : "*What's the difference between a class and a module?*"

Both can be used to structure and encapsulate data / behavior within my code ...

Searched a bit and found this resource which explained the difference (partly) to me : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7825002w(v=vs.90).aspx

But thinking a bit further based upon what is explain in the article:

**If I made a class with static properties and methods.** That would be quite similar to what a module is? Or am I wrong there?

So therefore my question:

**What's the difference between a module and a class with static members (like for example 'Math') ?**

Comment: Show some example of what you mean by the module. The module exports something, it can be a class or a function or just constants

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the hint. But I still don't see the great benefit of having modules. If I put static properties and methods upon a class I would basically accomplish the same.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: Have removed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules allow you to structure and separate your code. Depending on the module type that might be file based (for the external/es6 modules) or namespace based (for the internal modules), spread across multiple files.

There are multiple reasons to use modules instead of classes, like packaging and loading. Also, you can't declare a class inside another class, so unless you can structure your code in such a way that one class is enough to encapsulate an entire feature they won't be able to replace a module.

Comment: Okay. I think I get it: It's for having a language construct which enables me to contain an entire, complex feature (like for example "mechanicsMath")? While it wouldn't be possible or recommendable to cover such a complex part within one class?

Comment: @mizech yes, but not only. It could also go the opposite way - say, you only want to expose a single function - having an _entire class_ just for one thing is pretty much an overkill. It might even lead to a very unwieldy code - say you want to expose three different functions via a module - it it was a class, you'd have them all in one place but you might only be interested in one or two but not need the third. So, in short, it's about organising your code into manageable chunks.